# terraform not working with remote exec for tpl script

Tags: terraform

I have a simple aws ec2 instance as below

```
resource "aws_instance" "App01" {
    ##ami = "ami-846144f8"
    ami = "${data.aws_ami.aws_linux.id}"
    instance_type = "t1.micro"
    subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.public_1a.id}"
    associate_public_ip_address = true
    vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.web_server.id}","${aws_security_group.allow_ssh.id}"]
    key_name = "key"
    provisioner "remote-exec"{
        inline = ["${template_file.bootstrap.rendered}"]
    }
    tags {
        Name = "App01"
    }
```

}

```
data "aws_ami" "aws_linux" {
  most_recent = true
  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["amzn2-ami-*-x86_64-gp2"]
  }
  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }
  filter {
    name   = "owner-alias"
    values = ["amazon"]
  }
}


resource "template_file" "bootstrap" {
  template = "${file("bootstrap.tpl")}"
    vars {
      app01ip = "${aws_instance.App01.private_ip}"
      app02ip = "${aws_instance.App02.private_ip}"
      DBandMQip = "${aws_instance.DBandMQ.private_ip}"
    }
}
```

This is my tbl script

```
#!/bin/bash -xe
# install necessary items like ansible and
sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel
sudo amazon-linux-extras install ansible2


echo "${app01ip}  App01" > /etc/hosts
echo "${app02ip}  App02" > /etc/hosts
echo "${DBandMQip}  DBandMQ" > /etc/hosts
```

I keep getting a

```
Error: Error asking for user input: 1 error(s) occurred:

* Cycle: aws_instance.App01, template_file.bootstrap
```

I believe its coming from the resource portion for remote-exec but I am unsure whats wrong because it looks fine to me. Anyone has any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I might have misread but aren't you trying to put an ip address into a template and bootstrap an instance with that script but the instance is not yet created so the ip address is not known?

Maybe https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html

Comment: Ah I see. So then how can we do it. To automatically put the IP into the etc/hosts?

Comment: See eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31747836/circular-dependency-in-aws-stack-because-of-private-ip-aws-cloudformation but that'll only help with the local machine - app01 still won't know about app02... I'd suggest route53 really I think.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48184438/how-to-get-private-ip-of-ec-2-dynamically-and-put-it-in-etc-hosts might help too